# ChildBrowser plugin crashing in ios app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using ChildBrowser iOS cordova plugin for displaying pdf file.
when i rigorously scroll the pdf file which is opened in the child browser plugin,
the APP CRASHES with the following messages printed in the console.
seems to be a sort of memory issue

```
Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 backboardd[51] : BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 backboardd[51] : BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.InfoImage[0x2742][452]) : (UIKitApplication:com.InfoImage[0x2742]) Exited: Killed: 9

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 UserEventAgent[13] : jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 backboardd[51] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.InfoImage[0x2742]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 ReportCrash[480] : libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 ReportCrash[480] : Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2013-02-08-142310.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0

Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:09 MobComp-iPad-3 MobileWorkManager[452] : Received memory warning.

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 backboardd[51] : BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 backboardd[51] : BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.InfoImage[0x2742][452]) : (UIKitApplication:com.InfoImage[0x2742]) Exited: Killed: 9

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 UserEventAgent[13] : jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 backboardd[51] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.InfoImage[0x2742]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 ReportCrash[480] : libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary

Feb  8 14:23:10 MobComp-iPad-3 ReportCrash[480] : Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2013-02-08-142310.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
```

sometimes the app crashes and relaunches.
Thanks in advance. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the childbrowser plugin to newer version solved the issue.